# How to run a piece of code in a function every 0.2 seconds for 5 seconds?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

This it the function I want to call:

```
def server_fn():
    #the code below this line is the code I wanna run every 0.2s and stop after a total of 5s
    frame = url_to_image('http://192.168.180.161/1600x1200.jpg')
    ans = get_model_output(frame)
    if ans == 1 : 
        url = 'http://192.168.180.161/post/1'
    else:
        url = 'http://192.168.180.161/post/0'        
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.content)
```

Every time `server_fn()` is called, I want it to run that code 25 times in 5 seconds. How should I do that?

I tried this:

```
import threading

def printit():
    thread  = threading.Timer(1.0, printit)
    thread.start()
    x = 0
    if x == 10:
        thread.cancel()
    else:
        x += 1
        print(x)
    

printit()
```

but the output just displays 1 every line forever, and doesn't stop. This was just a test function I wanted to run to see if the function is running as I expected it to.

Comment: You're initializing `Timer()` in function which you pass into this timer. This leads to recursion and uncontrolled thread spam.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) if your task is to spawn a thread exact amount of times with some delay. It could be done with simple `for` loop and [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

...

for i in range(25):
    Thread(target=printit).start()  # spawn a thread
    sleep(0.2)  # delay
```

Here is a simple example of app which spawn a thread every 200 milliseconds:

```py
from threading import Thread, Lock
from time import time, sleep
from random import random

print_lock = Lock()

def safe_print(*args, **kwargs):
    print_lock.acquire()
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    print_lock.release()

def func(id_):
    sleep_time = random()
    safe_print(time(), id_, "- enter, sleep_time", sleep_time)
    sleep(sleep_time)
    safe_print(time(), id_, "- leave")

for i in range(25):
    safe_print(time(), "starting new thread with id", i)
    Thread(target=func, args=(i,)).start()
    sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

i = 0

while i!=25:
    
    "Your Code"
    
    sleep(0.2) #repeats the code after every 0.2 seconds delay 25 times (25*0.2 = 5 seconds)
    i = i+1
```

`i` would increase by 1 every 0.2 seconds until it reaches 25 which will make it exactly 5 seconds and stop the Loop